# Render nested relation from manage form in Backend

Tags: octobercms

I have 3 models '**Product**', '**Attribute**', '**Option**'.

Product **hasMany** Attributes **hasMany** Options

In my Product controller, I implemented RelationController to access to its Attributes on update context. It works fine.

But when I click on a attribute, i would like to manage the options of the attribute in the modal. 
And i stuck here because i dont find a way to initialize RelationController for the options through the product controller.

I think i need to extend RelationController to handle nested relations.

My yaml file for Attribute contains :

```
fields:
    name:
        label: Nom affiché
        type: text
        span: left

    api_id:
        label: Api ID
        span: right
        disabled: true

    options:
        label: Options
        type: partial
        path: $/acme/stuff/controllers/attributes/_field_options.htm
```

And in my _field_options.htm i have this :

```
<?= $this->relationRender('options') ?>
```

October responds

```
 "Relation behavior does not contain a definition for 'options'
```

Which is logical cause i'm calling this from a product context.

How can i do this ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to find a solution for displaying your nested relation?

Comment: I think it's not possible to do this directly with october. I should create a plugin.